# RealmSwift — updating UI takes forever

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I have a view on a collection of `RecentTrades` objects that are populated by a background task fetching using a `URLSession`.

My view looks like this:

```
struct StatusView: View {

    @ObservedResults(RecentTrades.self) var recentTrades

    func tradeCountColumn(x: RecentTrades) -> some View {
        Text(String(x.trades.count))
    }

    func isFetchingColumn(recentTrades: RecentTrades) -> some View {
        recentTrades.isFetching ? AnyView(ProgressView()) : AnyView(Text("Loaded"))
    }

    var body: some View {
        Table(recentTrades) {
            TableColumn("Pair", value: \.name)
            TableColumn("Trade count", content: tradeCountColumn)
            TableColumn("Loaded", content: isFetchingColumn)
        }
    }
    
}
```

My `RecentTrades` model looks like this:

```
class RecentTrades: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var name: String
    @Persisted var last: String
    @Persisted var trades: List<Trade>
    @Persisted var isFetching: Bool
    
}

class Trade: EmbeddedObject {
    
    @Persisted var price: String
    @Persisted var volume: String
    @Persisted(indexed: true) var time: Date
    @Persisted var buySell: BuySell
    @Persisted var marketLimit: MarketLimit
    @Persisted var miscellaneous: String
    
}
```

Unfortunately, this is super-slow. There are a number of `Task`s fetching trades using a `URLSession` for each pair of coins, but it is only when this view is open that the application grinds to a crawl in terms of responsiveness. I am really interested only in the `isFetching` property and the count of the `trades` `List` on my `RecentTrades` model.

There are around 50 or so `RecentTrades` objects in my Realm, and some of those have up to 1,000,000 `Trade`s in the `trades` property.

Is there a way to improve the efficiency of this view, so that I don't have to fetch the entire collection when any of the properties of the objects inside change? I know I an set up a change listener, but is this going to be any better? Will this still not deliver all of the objects, or does this method fetch lazily so that I can `count` without having to fetch all of the objects? Why does the `ObservedResults` not behave like this too?

Comment: Realm is fast; queries over thousands of objects happen almost instantly because the data being queried is stored locally. If you're having performance issues, it's likely not due to Realm. The code in the question is vague and there are a number of things that only YOU know what they do. We don't know about `isFetching`, `ProgressView` or `RecentTrades`. If I copy and paste that code into my app, it's blisteringly fast; but we don't know what else your app does. Please review the following guide: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Jay. I have improved my question, although admittedly I haven't produced all the associated code. I believe this is enough though; what do you think? Navigating around the rest of the app does not cause problems, it is only when this view is open. So I believe the problem lies with this view.

Comment: It's still pretty vague. Using .count won't affect performance. But without knowing more about what the other functions and properties do, it's hard to say. For example, suppose `recentTrades.isFetching` takes 1,000,000 objects and loads them into an *array* then iterates over them and calculates pi to the millionth digit. Well, first, that defeats the lazy loading nature of Realm (because the objects were added to an array) and then secondly, that calculation done 1,000,000 times takes a while. e.g. we don't know what the rest of your code does. As is, it's fast and works perfectly for me.